# List element not sorting properly

Tags: jquery, sorting

I wanted to sort `li` elements based on `data-order` but it is not sorting properly.

```
    <ul>
<li>Ten ** having 0<input type="checkbox" name="siz" data-order='0'/></li>
<li>Ten<input type="checkbox" name="siz" data-order='0'/></li>
<li>One <input type="checkbox" data-order='-1' name="One" value="1"/></li>
<li>Two <input type="checkbox" data-order='-2' name="twp"/></li>
<li>threee<input type="checkbox" name="thre" data-order='3'/></li>
<li>Four<input type="checkbox" name="for" data-order='4'/></li>
<li>Five<input type="checkbox" data-order='5' name="fibe"/></li>
<li>Six<input type="checkbox" name="siz" data-order='6'/></li>
<li>Seven<input type="checkbox" name="siz" data-order='7'/></li>
<li>Eight<input type="checkbox" name="siz" data-order='8'/></li>
<li>Nine<input type="checkbox" name="siz" data-order='9'/></li>
<li>Ten ** having 0<input type="checkbox" name="siz" data-order='0'/></li>

</ul>
```

```js
var elems = $('ul li');
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).find('input').attr('data-order') < $(b).find('input').attr('data-order')
}).appendTo(elems.parent());
```

What I am missing to sort the list of elements? See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6d92gy9y/

Comment: You want to order based on data-order attr, right??

Comment: @funcoding yes, you are right

Comment: One more thing! ascending or descending?

Comment: any, but need correct sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descending order:

```
var elems = $('ul li');

elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    if ($(a).find('input').attr('data-order') < $(b).find('input').attr('data-order'))
    return -1;
    if ($(a).find('input').attr('data-order') > $(b).find('input').attr('data-order'))
    return 1;
    return 0;

}).appendTo(elems.parent());
```

Comment: You are the champ!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you're comparing strings. If you use `data()` to get the values then jQuery will convert them to the correct type for you, `number` in this case. Try this:

```js
var $elems = $('ul li')
$elems.sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).find('input').data('order') > $(b).find('input').data('order');
}).appendTo($elems.closest('ul'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One <input type="checkbox" data-order="-1" name="One" value="1" /></li>
  <li>Two <input type="checkbox" data-order="-2" name="twp" /></li>
  <li>threee <input type="checkbox" data-order="3" name="thre" /></li>
  <li>for <input type="checkbox" data-order="4" name="for" /></li>
  <li>fibe <input type="checkbox" data-order="5" name="fibe" /></li>
  <li>siz <input type="checkbox" data-order="6" name="siz" /></li>
  <li>svn <input type="checkbox" data-order="7" name="siz" /></li>
  <li>eit <input type="checkbox" data-order="8" name="siz" /></li>
  <li>nin <input type="checkbox" data-order="9" name="siz" /></li>
  <li>tn <input type="checkbox" data-order="0" name="siz" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See my edits : Now you can understand my question, 10 is not properly sorting

Comment: It's sorting fine. The `data-order` value you gave is `0`, so it appears between `-1` and `1`

Comment: But why from bottom : two,one & eight. it should be two, one, tn, myten , three

Comment: That's because you're returning the `<` comparison. If you want to reverse the order compare by `>`. I updated the answer for you